# Work with checkboxes in docx file with Apache POI

Tags: java, checkbox, apache-poi, docx

could you please help me?
I need to fill checkboxes in my MS Word **docx** template via Apache POI. Checkboxes has been inserted by Developer tab->Controls->Checkbox and located inside paragraph -> "w:sdt" tag (not inside paragraph -> run).

I've tried `paragraph.getCTP().getFldSimpleList()` but it returns 0 fields.

So is there another way to get access for checkboxes?

XML part:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00C81ACC" w:rsidRDefault="00C81ACC" w:rsidP="004658AE">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:spacing w:line="276" w:lineRule="auto"/>
        <w:ind w:left="383" w:hanging="383"/>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
            <w:sz w:val="18"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="18"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:sdt>
        <w:sdtPr>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
                <w:sz w:val="18"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="18"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:id w:val="615721754"/>
            <w14:checkbox>
                <w14:checked w14:val="0"/>
                <w14:checkedState w14:val="2612" w14:font="MS Gothic"/>
                <w14:uncheckedState w14:val="2610" w14:font="MS Gothic"/>
            </w14:checkbox>
        </w:sdtPr>
        <w:sdtContent>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="MS Gothic" w:eastAsia="MS Gothic" w:hAnsi="MS Gothic" w:cs="Arial" w:hint="eastAsia"/>
                    <w:sz w:val="18"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="18"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>☐</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:sdtContent>
    </w:sdt>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
            <w:sz w:val="18"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="18"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> Pass</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by `apache poi` until now. And since it uses the extended `XML` from `w14` name space not even the underlying `ooxml-schema` classes supports this. Those schema classes were generated from the `XML` schemas of `Office Open XML` which was published in 2007. The extended `XML` from `w14` name space is later and not part of `Office Open XML`.

So if one wants supporting that then one needs working on very low level `XML` level. But for such a simple thing as a checkbox this can be shown here as an example.

The following code contains a working draft of a class `W14Checkbox`. This provides a static method to check whether a given `CTSdtRun` contains a `w14:checkbox`. If that is the case, then a `W14Checkbox` object can be created from that `CTSdtRun`. This object then provides `getChecked` and `setChecked` methods.

Note that in `setChecked` not only the boolean value `w14:checkbox/w14:checked` needs to be set but also the corresponding text value of the `CTSdtContentRun` needs to be set. This can be either Unicode Character 'BALLOT BOX' (U+2610) for not checked or Unicode Character 'BALLOT BOX WITH CHECK' (U+2612) for checked.

Complete Example:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class WordFillCheckBox {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("source.docx"));

  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) { //go through all paragraphs
   for (CTSdtRun sdtRun : paragraph.getCTP().getSdtList()) {
    if (W14Checkbox.isW14Checkbox(sdtRun)) {
     W14Checkbox w14Checkbox = new W14Checkbox(sdtRun);
     System.out.println(w14Checkbox.getChecked());
     if (w14Checkbox.getChecked()) w14Checkbox.setChecked(false); else w14Checkbox.setChecked(true);
     System.out.println(w14Checkbox.getChecked());
    }
   }
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("result.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }

 static class W14Checkbox {
  CTSdtRun sdtRun = null;
  CTSdtContentRun sdtContentRun = null;
  XmlObject w14CheckboxChecked = null;

  W14Checkbox(CTSdtRun sdtRun) {
   this.sdtRun = sdtRun;
   this.sdtContentRun = sdtRun.getSdtContent();
   String declareNameSpaces = "declare namespace w14='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml'";
   XmlObject[] selectedObjects = sdtRun.getSdtPr().selectPath(declareNameSpaces + ".//w14:checkbox/w14:checked");
   if (selectedObjects.length > 0) {  
    this.w14CheckboxChecked  = selectedObjects[0];
   }
  }
  CTSdtContentRun getContent() {
   return this.sdtContentRun;
  }
  XmlObject getW14CheckboxChecked() {
   return this.w14CheckboxChecked;
  }
  boolean getChecked() {
   XmlCursor cursor = this.w14CheckboxChecked.newCursor();
   String val = cursor.getAttributeText(new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml", "val", "w14"));
   return "1".equals(val) || "true".equals(val);
  }
  void setChecked(boolean checked) {
   XmlCursor cursor = this.w14CheckboxChecked.newCursor();
   String val = (checked)?"1":"0";
   cursor.setAttributeText(new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml", "val", "w14"), val);
   cursor.dispose();
   CTText t = this.sdtContentRun.getRArray(0).getTArray(0);
   String content = (checked)?"\u2612":"\u2610";
   t.setStringValue(content);
  }

  static boolean isW14Checkbox(CTSdtRun sdtRun) {
   CTSdtPr sdtPr = sdtRun.getSdtPr();
   String declareNameSpaces = "declare namespace w14='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml'";
   XmlObject[] selectedObjects = sdtPr.selectPath(declareNameSpaces + ".//w14:checkbox");
   if (selectedObjects.length > 0) return true;  
   return false;
  }
 }
}
```

Note: This is a working draft only and needs to be further developed to be ready for productive usage.

Comment: Hi All, I also have a similar issue, but this code check the box if its unchecked and vice versa, I need to check the check box on basis of some condition for example suppose there are three checkbox A , B,C depending upon some condition i need to check the checkbox but i can't find any unique property through which i can identify that it is checkbox A or B or C