# How to create a checkbox in docx with NPOI

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx, npoi

How does one create a checkbox within a docx document with NPOI? I have seen example where it is done with POI in Java, but not in the .Net version.

Here is the Java example:
[Work with checkboxes in docx file with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58728103/work-with-checkboxes-in-docx-file-with-apache-poi)

Answer (score 0):

I went with the Open Xml Sdk library instead of NPOI. It supports the creation of form checkboxes.

Open Xml Sdk documentation start:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk

Checkbox documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.checkbox?view=openxml-2.8.1

Comment: Would be nice if you showed some actual details of what you did.